# Use my php variable as a formula to calculate something

Tags: php

I'm working in an invoice system, that has to calculate different formulas for every product, which will need to be filled with Width, Height, and Material cost.

I did a database where i'm storing

```
t_title -> "Curtain 1"

t_formula -> "({ANCHO}*{ALTURA})*{PRECIO}"
```

and then php does this:

```
<?php 
   $ancho = str_replace("{ANCHO}", $_POST['ancho'], $articulo['t_formula']);
   $alto = str_replace("{ALTURA}", $_POST['alto'], $ancho);
   $precio = str_replace("{PRECIO}", $_POST['precio'], $alto);
   $total = $precio; echo eval($total);
?>
```

and the result  is not giving anything, but a blank space.

How can i make it to work? I know that php can't calculate from variables as php but, i can't find another way to do it.

Comment: Does `t_formula` have `x`s or `*`s in it?

Comment: * but the site wasn't showing them and i replaced it.

Comment: `*`s are formatting elements in markdown. I edited the question so the variable is displayed properly.

Comment: Be mindful using [`eval()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

Comment: Echo $total and make sure it looks right first

Comment: `echo $total;` gives `(10*10)*1000`

Comment: `1000;echo DB_PASSWORD;echo DB_USERNAME;`

Answer (score 1):

The eval() function expects the string parameter to be a proper code statement.

```
$str = '(10*10) * 1000';
echo eval($str);
```

will give you an error, because php cannot evaluate that string. However,

```
$str = 'return (10*10) * 1000;';
echo eval($str);
```

will evaluate the expression correctly.

You should use:

```
$total = 'return ' . $precio . ';';
echo eval($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using `eval` is wrong. The string passed to eval must be valid PHP code. i.e:

```
$precio2 = '$total = '.$precio.';';
eval($precio2);
echo $total;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: @davco98 take care with the edit of the answer, I added `;` at the last to the string to be valid PHP code.